# How should I use jQuery with Sunspot in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I just want to display the search result in the same page without redirecting to default search link like ".....search=&commit=Search". My original intention is use jQuery to render the same form with the search result.
And the remote option is set below

```
>   <%= form_tag index_by_dvp_path,:method => :get do %>
>        <p>
>           <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
>           <%= submit_tag "Search",remote: true %>
>        </p>
>        <% end %>
```

But when I click the search button, the page still redirects to the default link as I mentioned.

I'm not sure where it the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:remote => true` option for the search form

```
<%= form_tag index_by_dvp_path,:method => :get, :remote => true do %>
  <p>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search",remote: true %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and submit the form to an action that will fetch the results of your search in controller. Also respond with `format.js` in the same method

```
def index_by_dvp
  @values = Model.where(params[:search])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**in index_by_dvp.js.erb**

```
$('#your_div_for_search_result').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'your_search_partial')%>")
```